# Flutter: best filetype for animated images

Tags: flutter, file, animation, gif

Id realy prefer not to use gifs because of their performance issues, is there a better filetype that can play an animated image without neading something like a video loader?

Comment: I prefer rive for complex animation

Answer (score 1):

you can use riv. file type from rive.

```
RiveAnimation.asset('assets/truck.riv');
```

[rive for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/rive), and [here](https://rive.app/) you can build your own animation

Answer (score 0):

you can try json filetype as it is light weight and it can reload fast

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lottie animations (json). Please check this link

https://pub.dev/packages/lottie

All you have to add it

```dart
Lottie.asset('assets/LottieLogo1.json'),

// Load a Lottie file from a remote url
Lottie.network('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/master/example/assets/Mobilo/A.json'),
```

You can find animations from this link

https://lottiefiles.com